# Type inference for overloaded function with enum params?

Tags: typescript

Is it possible to perform type inference using an overloaded function with an enum param? For example, say I'm trying to make a factory function whose return type depends on enum value:

```js
enum Colors {
  Red,
  Green
};

abstract class Box { };
class RedBox extends Box { };
class GreenBox extends Box { };

class BoxFactory {
  static createBox(color: Colors.Red): RedBox;
  static createBox(color: Colors): Box {
    switch (color) {
      case Colors.Red:
        return new RedBox();
      case Colors.Green:
        return new GreenBox();
    }
  } 
}

function makeMeABox(color: Colors) {
  // Argument of type 'Colors' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Colors.Red'
  return BoxFactory.createBox(color);
}
```

([playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=enum%20Colors%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20Red%2C%0D%0A%20%20Green%0D%0A%7D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Aabstract%20class%20Box%20%7B%20%7D%3B%0D%0Aclass%20RedBox%20extends%20Box%20%7B%20%7D%3B%0D%0Aclass%20GreenBox%20extends%20Box%20%7B%20%7D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20BoxFactory%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20static%20createBox(color%3A%20Colors.Red)%3A%20RedBox%3B%0D%0A%20%20static%20createBox(color%3A%20Colors)%3A%20Box%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20switch%20(color)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20case%20Colors.Red%3A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20new%20RedBox()%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20case%20Colors.Green%3A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20new%20GreenBox()%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%7D%20%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Afunction%20makeMeABox(color%3A%20Colors)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%2F%2F%20Argument%20of%20type%20'Colors'%20is%20not%20assignable%20to%20parameter%20of%20type%20'Colors.Red'%0D%0A%20%20return%20BoxFactory.createBox(color)%3B%0D%0A%7D))

If I generate a declarations file, the general overload doesn't even show up. However, things are fine if I remove the overload `static createBox(color: Colors.Red): RedBox;`.

Comment: Return type is never considered part of a function signature even in statically typed languages like Java and C++

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are only missing one signature:

```
class BoxFactory {
  static createBox(color: Colors.Red): RedBox;
  static createBox(color: Colors): Box; // <--- THIS ONE
  static createBox(color: Colors): Box {
    switch (color) {
      case Colors.Red:
        return new RedBox();
      case Colors.Green:
        return new GreenBox();
    }
  } 
}
```

Then:

```
let a = BoxFactory.createBox(Colors.Red); // type of a is RedBox
let b = BoxFactory.createBox(Colors.Green); // type of b is Box
```

([code in playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=enum%20Colors%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20Red%2C%0D%0A%20%20Green%0D%0A%7D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Aabstract%20class%20Box%20%7B%20%7D%3B%0D%0Aclass%20RedBox%20extends%20Box%20%7B%20%7D%3B%0D%0Aclass%20GreenBox%20extends%20Box%20%7B%20%7D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20BoxFactory%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20static%20createBox(color%3A%20Colors.Red)%3A%20RedBox%3B%0D%0A%20%20static%20createBox(color%3A%20Colors)%3A%20Box%3B%0D%0A%20%20static%20createBox(color%3A%20Colors)%3A%20Box%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20switch%20(color)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20case%20Colors.Red%3A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20new%20RedBox()%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20case%20Colors.Green%3A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20new%20GreenBox()%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%7D%20%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Afunction%20makeMeABox(color%3A%20Colors)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20return%20BoxFactory.createBox(color)%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Alet%20a%20%3D%20BoxFactory.createBox(Colors.Red)%3B%20%2F%2F%20type%20of%20a%20is%20RedBox%0D%0Alet%20b%20%3D%20BoxFactory.createBox(Colors.Green)%3B%20%2F%2F%20type%20of%20b%20is%20Box))

Comment: Your approach works great, thanks! Can you help me understand why we need the extra overload that is the same as the function signature? Does the compiler not resolve the primary function signature if overloaded?

Comment: The signature of the actual implementation isn't part of the overloads list, meaning that in your code there's only one signature (where `color = Colors.Red`), my code adds the 2nd signature for the general case. It's just that in this case the signature of the implementation matches it.